# Is it possible to specify a WHERE clause for a Unique Constraint (filtered index) on a table in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I use the Generate DLL from Enterprise Architect, but I need a filtered index (e.g. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo ON dbo.bar(key) WHERE key IS NOT NULL;`).  How can I enter this Enterprise Architect (I'm on version <s>**13.0.1307**</s> **15.0.1511** and the database is SQL Server).

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show the code you're using now and what error you're getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error on the `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX' statement.  That works great. The question is how do I enter that in Enterprise Architect, so that the next time i generate the DDL for the database, the filtered index is included.

Comment: Don't see any functionality for this, but you can always add the where clause to the generated ddl

Comment: Have you tried reverse engineering a database with such a filtered index? When you then generate the DDL that should hopefully result in the same database structure